# Data-Bind attribute value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a checkboxlist which is being binded from the database and Id of the checkbox is being binded with the help of data-bind attribute and when the user clicks the submit button I'm iterating through the checkboxlist and checking whether the Checkbox is checked on not, if it is checked then i want get the Id of the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox"  class='roles' name='roles' data-bind="attr: { value: Id }" />
```

This is how i tried

```
  if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
  if (this.checked)
  {
   var input = $(this);
   if ($(input).data().bind) {
    alert($(this).data('bind'));
  }
  }
 }
```

i actually want to get this value `data-bind="attr: { value: Id }`

But in the alertbox im getting message as data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, where as i want to get 1,2 etc

Comment: Note that after `var input = $(this)`, `input` is *already* a jQuery instance. No need to then repeat the `$()` by doing `$(input)`. It's harmless, but pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But in the alertbox im getting message as data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, where as i want to get 1,2 etc

Right, the value of `data-bind` hasn't changed. If you want the value of the `value` attribute, you need to get that instead:

```
alert(input.val());
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/zafakobe/3):

```
var obj = {Id: "foo"};

ko.applyBindings(obj, document.body);
display("data-bind: " + $("input").data().bind);
display("value: " + $("input").val());
```

---

Side note: Knockout has a `value` binding for setting the value of a form control:

```
<input data-bind="value: Id">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect syntax to get data attribute. You need to use:

```
$(this).data('bind')
```

**[Refer to .data() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

Comment: Actually, the given syntax works as well. If you call `data` with no arguments, you get back an object with the information stored on it as properties. This is about three-quarters of the way down the page you linked. Example: http://jsbin.com/zafakobe/1

Comment: im getting the message in the messagebox as data-bind="attr: { value: Id }

Comment: And in fact, the question was buried at the end of the question: The OP **is** getting the value of `data-bind`, just not the value they expected to get.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this way:

```
var value = $(input).data("bind");
```

or this way:

```
var value =$(input).attr("data-bind");
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer the question of why what the OP's doing (which is valid) doesn't work.

Comment: im getting the message in the messagebox as data-bind="attr: { value: Id }

Comment: you mean ``data().bind()`` in valid?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Yes, `.data().bind` (no `()`) is valid.